# Absolute continuity of distributions --- why do we need this?

Tags: distributions, random-variable, continuous-data, cumulative-distribution-function

Why do we define continuous probability distribution as those with absolutely continuous CDF, instead of just continuous CDF?

Comment: Thanks, the link you provided is very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find more detail on this issue in a related question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298293/).  Absolute continuity of the CDF is a stronger condition than continuity, and essentially just means that the distribution has a valid *density function*.  For example, if the CDF $F$ of a real scalar random variable is absolutely continuous then there exists a real function $f$ (the density) such that:

$$F(x) = \int \limits_{-\infty}^x f(x) dx.$$

This requirement does not hold for all continuous distributions.  There are some nasty distributions (such as the notorious [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function)) that are continuous, but are not absolutely continuous, so they have no density function that satisfies the above equation.

This isn't really a matter of how we *define* the distributions.  It's just that, in practice, all the uniformly continuous distributions we use in statistics are also absolutely continuous ---i.e., they have valid density functions.  You will occasionally encounter cases of random variables that are a mixture of continuous and discrete parts, but practical applications do not give rise to the dread cases where you have a continuous, but not absolutely continuous, distribution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very helpful.

Comment: I"m curious what you mean by a "uniformly continuous distribution."  One example I am puzzling over is any Beta$(a,b)$ distribution where $a$ or $b$ is less than $1.$