# Continuous distribution when there are flat regions

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

Consider a distribution function $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$ definining the positive, finite measures $\mu_F$ determined by
$$
\mu_F((a,b])\equiv F(b)-F(a)
$$
for each $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ with $b> a$.

Suppose $F$ is such that $\mu_F((1,3])=0$.

Can $F$ still be a continuous distribution (i.e., a continuous function) in the sense outlined [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298293/absolutely-continuous-random-variable-vs-continuous-random-variable)?

(Note, I'm asking whether $F$ can be a continuous distribution. I'm not referring to the concept of absolute continuity)

Comment: The CDF $F$ of any Beta distribution (for instance) satisfies your assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make lots of examples by taking mixtures of compactly supported distributions where the supports are some positive distance apart.

For example, let $f_n = 2 \mathbf 1_{[n, n + 1/2]}$ so $f_n$ is the density of a uniform RV on $[n, n + 1/2]$ (I could have done this with translated beta distributions too, among many others). Then if I take
$$
f  =\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n 2^{-n-1}
$$
(where I'm using $2^{-n-1}$ as the mixing probability, but any other distribution over $\mathbb N$ could be used) I have a continuous density over $\mathbb R$. The corresponding CDF will be flat on $(n+1/2, n+1)$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$ since the density there is zero so the integration adds nothing. But this is a perfectly valid distribution and is continuous.

Here's what this looks like (just the beginning at least). Not only does the CDF have some flat regions but it has a countable infinity of them.

[image: density ands cdf]