# Implications of continuity of a distribution function

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

Consider a random vector $(X,Y)$ with distribution function $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow [0,1]$ and let $\mu_F$ be the associated measure.

Take any $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and consider the set
$$
\mathcal{R}_{(a,b)}\equiv \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x+a=y+b\}.
$$

Is assuming that $F$ is a continuous distribution (in the sense outlined [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298293/absolutely-continuous-random-variable-vs-continuous-random-variable)) sufficient to ensure that
$$
\mu_F(\mathcal{R}_{(a,b)})=0 \text{ }\forall (a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2
$$
or do we need absolute continuity (or, other conditions?)

Comment: I believe you can reduce the problem by a dimension, making it instantly answerable: simply consider the random variable $X-Y.$

Comment: Thanks. Therefore, I think I need absolute continuity, correct?

Comment: Absolute continuity would be sufficient.  It's not a necessary condition.  Any necessary condition would be equivalent to $X-Y$ having an absolutely continuous distribution.  There are distributions on the plane that are not absolutely continuous yet have one absolutely continuous marginal (and you can think of the distribution of $X-Y$ as a marginal after rotating the picture by 45 degrees).